# LINQ to select items in collections with differing types

Tags: c#, linq

How would one implement LINQ to extract the Guid's from one collection of objects of type A such that they can exclude these Guids from another collection of objects of type B.   Object A and Object B both have a Guid field called 'ID."

I have the following:

1. `ObservableCollection<Component> component`  Component has a
   field called `ID` of type `Guid`
2. `ObservableCollection<ComponentInformation> ComponentInformationCollection` ComponentInformation
   has a field called `ID` of type `Guid`

My implementation:

```
component =>
{
    if (component != null)
    {
        var cancelledComponents = new List<ComponentInformation>();
        foreach (Component comp in component)
        {
            cancelledComponents.Add(new ComponentInformation() { ID = comp.ID });
        }
        this.ComponentInformationCollection.Remove(cancelledComponents);
    }
});
```

I believe there is a more elegant solution which I've been working at to solve but the issue I keep running into is creating a 'new ComponentInformation' such that the types do not give me an error.

====== FINAL SOLUTION =======

```
var cancelledComponentIDs = new HashSet<Guid>(component.Select(x => x.ID));
this.ComponentInformationCollection.Remove(
     this.ComponentInformationCollection.Where(x => cancelledComponentIDs.Contains(x.ID)).ToList());
```

Thank you to:
Jason - I used this as a template for my final solution (listed below).
Servy - While I could have used a comparer, I think for this particular scenario a comparer was not neccessary because of its one-time-use type of situation.

ComponentInformationCollection is a Silverlight DependencyProperty that will trigger a INotifyChangedEvent (MVVM pattern) when altered, so the solution above worked best for my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
var ids = new HashSet<Guid>(
              component.Select(x => x.ID)
          );
var keepers = ComponentInformationCollection.Where(x => !ids.Contains(x.ID));
```

Comment: That's a lot of work to just not define an `IEqualityComparer` for `Component`.  You do two extra projections, an extra where, and you need to put everything into the HashSet (meaning no streaming).

Comment: Be incredibly careful with using Contains inside LINQ Where clauses, for every item that is being considered for return you are doing a collection wide operation of the ids HashSet. If either collection grows too large or worst case both, this query will skyrocket in execution time. Essentially, it follows O(n) algorithmic speed which states for every additional item added it will scale by a set amount TL;DR: Each item makes it slower.

Answer (score 1):

If `Component` doesn't already define an Equals and GetHashCode that uses the ID to do the compare you can define a comparer such as this:

```
class ComponentComparer : IEqualityComparer<Component>
{
  public int Compare(Component a, Component b)
  {
    return a.ID.CompareTo(b.ID);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(Component a)
  {
    return a.ID.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
var result = componentCollectionA.Except(componentCollectionB, new ComponentComparer());
```

(written off of the top of my head; may require minor modifications to get it to compile.)

Comment: No, the types are different in the two collections. That's the whole point and why you can't just use `Except`.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ will allow you to find the GUIDs you need, but LINQ sequences are generally immutable; you'll still need to use some kind of loop to actually change the collection. The trick is getting the correct instances of your original collection that you want to remove.

Implementing one of the equality/comparison interfaces is one way to go, and if you need to compare your objects for equality in multiple places, is definitely the way to go. If you don't want to do that, this should get you what you want:

```
var removeme = (from x in this.ComponentInformationCollection
               join y in component on x.ID equals y.ID
               select x).ToList();
removeme.ForEach(x => this.ComponentInformationCollection.Remove(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out loud (meaning I didn't create a project and types and compile this), but how about:

```
var cancelledComponents = component.Select(c=> new ComponentInformation() {ID = c.ID}).ToList();
cancelledComponents.ForEach(c => ComponentInformationCollection.Remove(c));
```

Comment: This will work if the object implements IEquatable or similar; otherwise the new instances of ComponentInformation won't be equal to the ones in the original collection.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to solve this...  this is a pretty simple Linq statement to query the ones you are looking for from the collection.

```
var keep = typeAList.Where(a => typeBList.FirstOrDefault(b => a.ID == b.ID) == null);
```

Here is the little test app I put together to demo it.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<TypeA> typeAList = new List<TypeA>();
            typeAList.Add(new TypeA() { ID = Guid.NewGuid() });
            typeAList.Add(new TypeA() { ID = Guid.NewGuid() });
            typeAList.Add(new TypeA() { ID = Guid.NewGuid() });

            List<TypeB> typeBList = new List<TypeB>();
            typeBList.Add(new TypeB() { ID = typeAList[0].ID });
            typeBList.Add(new TypeB() { ID = typeAList[1].ID });

            //this is the statement
           var keep = typeAList.Where(a => typeBList.FirstOrDefault(b => a.ID == b.ID) == null);
        }
    }

    class TypeA
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
    }

    class TypeB
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This is close to maximally inefficient while still being a reasonable implementation. Don't use `Count` when you mean `Any`, and don't repeatedly linearly scan the collection when you can be more efficient  by building a set that can check containment very quickly.

Comment: Good call on the count statement...  I updated and removed the second full scan as well.